# Sporadically losing web.config settings after app pool recycle

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis-7, web-config

We have an asp.net application on IIS7, with a services directory containing the following in its `web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet" />
        <add name="HttpPost" />
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This allows the webservices in that directory to operate without issue. Every night, we recycle the app pool on all webservers.  Sometimes (3x in the last 10 days) a webserver loses this config when the app pool completes recycling and calls to the webservices in that directory on that webserver fail.  Recycling the app pool fixes the issue.

Has anyone seen this behavior before?  I realize one possible resolution would be to stop recycling the pools but I'd like to figure out the root issue.  Thanks in advance...

Comment: I think the web.config is read in when your web application starts / restarts.  Perhaps you need to explicitly restart the web app after the app pool has been restarted.  Just a guess, though (and it's a reach).